# Send your IP to VPS through Python3 socket module

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, vps

I am working on a way to control my laptop from my VPS (in python3). So far, I have some code which (on the laptop) accepts batch commands from the server via a socket and (on the server) can send out commands to the specified IP via a socket. My problem is that the IP of my laptop changes as I connect to a different network or after some time due to DHCP.

What I'm working on right now, is a way of sending my current IP to the server (which has a static IP).

The problem is that an IP can vary in length and so I cannot specify the size on the server program.

My code so far is as follows:

**Program running on the VPS:**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, gethostbyname
import sys

#This part is for getting the client IP#
getPORT_NUMBER = 8080
getSIZE = 1024
gethostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

getSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
getSocket.bind( (hostName, getPORT_NUMBER) )

print("Waiting for client connection on port: {0}\n".format(getPORT_NUMBER))
while True:
        (received,addr) = getSocket.recvfrom(getSIZE)
        ipGet = received.decode("utf-8")
sys.exit()
#-------------#
PORT = 80
SIZE = 1024

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.connect( (SERVER_IP, PORT) )
print ("Ready to send packets to host: {0}, on port {1}".format(SERVER_IP, PORT))
while True:
        sendMsg = input('rootApp@' + SERVER_IP + ':~# ')
        mySocket.sendto(sendMsg.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT))
sys.exit()
```

**Code running on my laptop:**

```
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, gethostname
import sys
import os

PORT_NUMBER = 80
SIZE = 1024
C_IP = gethostbyname(gethostname())
hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )
#This part is for sending the IP to the server#
SERVER_IP   = 'real.server.ip.here'
PORT = 8080
SIZE = 1024

server = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
server.connect( (SERVER_IP, PORT) )
server.sendto(C_IP.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT))
#---------------#
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print("Listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))
print('--Command History--')
while True:
        (received,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        command = received.decode("utf-8")
        print(command)
        os.system(command)
sys.exit()
```

I am aware that there may be various mistakes in the code and I would appreciate pointing them out however I am mainly looking for an answer to my actual question.

**NOTE 1:** If someone could include some simple encryption I could use, I would be very grateful.

**NOTE 2:** Before someone marks this question as a duplicate or gives a link to a similar question, I would like to mention that I have gone through multiple questions and websites which I simply could not understand. I need an answer explained at 'noob-level'.

Thank you in advance :)

**-----------SOLUTION-----------**

I found a solution mostly thanks to georgexsh (and Google :). While this is probably not the best or most efficient way of doing this, it certainly works (on python3, tested on Win7).

The code is:

**Running on the laptop:**

```
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, gethostname
import sys
import os

PORT_NUMBER = 80
SIZE = 1024
hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )
#---------------#
print('Connecting to server...')
SERVER_IP = 'real.server.ip.here' # Make sure you edit this
PORT = 8080 # Any port other than the port you set on the other variable
getSIZE = 1
sendConn = 'A'
print('...') # All print() statements are optional
server = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
server.connect( (SERVER_IP, PORT) )
server.sendto(sendConn.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP, PORT))
print('...')
#---------------#
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )
print('...')
print('Connected!\n')
print("Listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))
print('--Command History--')
while True:
        (received,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        command = received.decode("utf-8")
        print(command)
        os.system(command) # Execute the command in cmd. This can be replaced with anything you want your program to do with the data you send.
sys.exit() # Optional
```

**Code running on the VPS:**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, gethostbyname
import sys

#-------------#
getPORT_NUMBER = 8080 # Port numbers have to match the ones in the code above!
getSIZE = 1
gethostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

getSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
getSocket.bind( (gethostName, getPORT_NUMBER) )

print("Waiting for connection on port {0}\n".format(getPORT_NUMBER))
dataGet = ''
while dataGet != 'A' :
        dataGet, clientAddr = getSocket.recvfrom(getSIZE)
        dataGet = dataGet.decode('utf-8')
#-------------#
PORT = 80
SIZE = 1024
SERVER_IP = clientAddr[0] # Important, this caused the error I wrote about in the comments under the answer!
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.connect( (SERVER_IP, PORT) )
print ("Ready to communicate with host: {0}, on port {1}".format(SERVER_IP, PORT))
while True:
        sendMsg = input('rootApp@' + SERVER_IP + ':~# ') # Input text is editable.
        mySocket.sendto(sendMsg.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT))
sys.exit() # Optional
```

Comment: "my laptop" *checks profile pic* hmmmm -_-

Comment: @SuperStew That profile pic is old. I was gonna change it ages ago. Anyway... How is this relevant?

Comment: Just because Kali is "the hacker linux" and you were talking about remote controlling computers

Comment: Yeah, I know. I have it on my laptop (dual boot). If it annoys you, I can change it? 
Edit: Just so you don't think of me as a script kiddie, I don't consider myself a hacker, I'm just learning stuff.

Comment: Lol nah man, was just making a funny.

Comment: ._.        okay, thanks for adding a bit of humour to my question ;)

Comment: can you use tcp instead of udp here?

Comment: @georgexsh I could but, how do I change the protocol? Is it just changing the port or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use address returned by `recvfrom()` directly?

> ... The return value is a pair (bytes, address) where bytes is a bytes object representing the data received and address is the address of the socket sending the data.

```
received, addr = getSocket.recvfrom(getSIZE)
print(addr)
```

yields:

```
('202.149.20.224', 51050)
```

Comment: Um, sorry, I don't quite get you. Do I just replace `(received,addr)` with `received, addr`? So just get rid of the brackets. Sorry if this is an obvious question but I am a noob to sockets in python.

Comment: parentheses are irrelevant here ... the IP address of client is in `addr` var, try it.

Comment: So, wait, I can send anything through the socket and use this to get the IP it came from?

Comment: yes, if you only want to get the IP, that how socket works, the server has to know the address of the client to transmit data back.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna test it out tomorrow. If it works for me, I will accept your answer straight away. Thanks. That is a super easy way of doing it.

Comment: So, I modified the code in the comments as follows:
**Client-Side**
`#---------------#
print('Connecting to server...')
SERVER_IP = 'real.ip.goes.here'
PORT = 8080
getSIZE = 1
sendConn = 'A'
print('...')
server = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
server.connect( (SERVER_IP, PORT) )
server.sendto(sendConn.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP, PORT))
print('...')
#---------------#`

Comment: and **Server-Side**
`#-------------#
getPORT_NUMBER = 8080
getSIZE = 1
gethostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

getSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
getSocket.bind( (gethostName, getPORT_NUMBER) )

print("Waiting for connection on port {0}\n".format(getPORT_NUMBER))
dataGet = ''
while dataGet != 'A' :
        dataGet, clientAddr = getSocket.recvfrom(getSIZE)
        dataGet = dataGet.decode('utf-8')
#-------------#`

Comment: I get the error on my SSH client: `TypeError: string or unicode text buffer expected, not tuple`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Any suggestions?

EDIT: I only get that error once I open the client-side program.

Comment: @user9123 no idea what the problem is, don't make your question a moving target, resolve this one first and go ask another.

Comment: Um, sorry if I made this too confusing. It's just that I tried to apply what you said to my current work and it didn't go so well. I'll try to find the answer on google. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you should always post full traceback, update it to your original question.

Comment: I found the answer now. Your answer really helped a lot in making this work. I am accepting your answer. Thanks for replying to the comments also because this is another thing which helped a lot. I will update my question with the complete solution so any future problems can be solved easily.

Comment: @user9123 `addr` is a tuple, `(client_ip, client_port)`, so `client_ip = addr[0]`.

Comment: Yeah. I kinda just converted it into a string and removed the unnecessary chars from the front and back. It works too xD

Comment: @user9123 nope, your "method" will fail with different ip or port digits length, that is not programming.

Comment: That is a fair point. I will fix it now. Thanks sooooo much. I would double accept your answer if I could :)